# Multiplatform single-file storage

Tags: java, file-storage

I need a way to store several images in one/two (some projects seems to us an index too) for both .NET and java. The file-format needs to be easy to decompress (I'm planing to do so on android).

And also, for each file I need to be able to store the following metadata: file-index, name, md5-checksum.

Also, the footprint of the framework should not be to big.

And last, if you got any simple solutions to the problem, I don't need a framework, but could with some guidance probably code it myself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip seems like the obvious choice. You can store an additional file containing any metadata not already provided by zip. The format is well defined and there are a wealth of tools available.

Comment: There's no need to use zip, it uses compression but images are already self-compressed. I would pick tar as a container.

Comment: You can use the zip container without compression (stored).